# Szemerédi-Trotter theorem unit area triangles

Tags: combinatorial-geometry

Let $P$ be a set of $n$ points in the plane. Show that there are at most $O(n^{7/3})$ triangles of unit area whose vertices are from $P$ by using Szemeredi-Trotter theorem.

Comment: Fix a point $p \in P$. Then for any other point $q$, if $pqr$ make a unit triangle then $r$ must lie on one of two lines (that are parallel to the segment $pq$). That means the number of such triangles that include the point $p$ are counted by incidence between $P$ and $O(n)$ lines so Szemeredi-Trotter gives $O(n^{4/3})$. Then multiply by $n$ for all possible $p$ to get $O(n^{7/3})$.

Answer (score 0):

Sandeep has sketched the solution in the comments. Let me fill in the details (and also get this question out of the "unanswered questions" queue).

Let us recall the Szemerédi-Trotter theorem, first published in their paper *Extremal problems in discrete geometry* (Combinatorica 1983):

**Theorem (Szemerédi and Trotter 1983)** Suppose there are $n$ points and $\ell$ lines on the plane $\mathbb{R}^2$. The number of incidences between points and lines is at most $c( (n \ell)^{2/3} + n + \ell$) for some absolute constant $c>0$.

Here, an incidence just means a pair $(P, L)$ where $P$ is a point and $L$ is a line from our collection and $P\in L$. When $\ell=n$, we see that the number of incidences is $O( n^{4/3})$. Of course, when $\ell = 2n$ or more generally $\ell = \lambda n$ (for some fixed $\lambda$), then again the number of incidences is at most $O(n^{4/3})$. A particularly elegant proof of Szemerédi-Trotter theorem was given by Székely in his paper *[Crossing Numbers and Hard Erdös Problems in Discrete Geometry](https://www.cs.umd.edu/%7Egasarch/TOPICS/erdos_dist/szekely.pdf)* (Combinatorics, Probability and Computing 1993). Székely's proof used the crossing lemma (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4574812/49227) for a statement).

We can now prove the following result.

**Proposition.** Given $n$ points on the plane, they determine at most $O(n^{7/3})$ triangles of unit area.

By "determine", we mean that the triangle has vertices coming from the collection of points under consideration.

**Proof.** Let us fix a point $P$ from our collection, and try to understand how many unit area triangles are possible where $P$ is one of the vertices. Well, we first need to connect $P$ to another point $Q$ in the collection to get a side of the triangle. Consider the line $\overline{PQ}$ joining them. For a third point $R$ to be the remaining vertex of the triangle, it needs to be positioned anywhere on a particular line paralell to $\overline{PQ}$ with a prescribed distance away (and there are two possible parallel lines, one for each side of the line $\overline{PQ}$). In other words, the number of unit triangles where one of the vertices is $P$ can be counted by analyzing the number of incidences between the points in the collection (other than $P$, so there are $n-1$ points) and the 2 parallel lines joining $P$ to other points $Q$ (and again, there are at most $2(n-1)$ such lines). By corollary to Szemerédi-Trotter theorem, there are at most $O(n^{4/3})$ such incidences, which gives an upper bound for the number of unit area triangles where $P$ is one of the vertices. But now we must vary over $P$ among all $n$ different points in the collection, giving us a total of at most $n\cdot O(n^{4/3}) = O(n^{7/3})$ many triangles of unit area all of whose vertices come from our collection.